# Чтение данных из файла в С

Tags: c

Не получается вывести в программе данные, считанные из файла input.txt. Файл находится в директории проекта и содержит строчку чисел - **5  100   95   5    10   45   50**. Сама программа выводит какой-то мусор. В чем может быть ошибка?

Файл `main.c`

```
#include "function.h"

int main() {

    double N, U1, U2, tn, t1, t2, tk;
    int x;

    sposob_vvoda(&x, &N, &U1, &U2, &tn, &t1, &t2, &tk);

    return 0;
}
```

Файл `function.h`

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < math.h >

void sposob_vvoda(int *x, double *N, double *U1, double *U2, double *tn, double *t1, double *t2, double *tk);
```

Файл `function.c`

```
#include "function.h"

void sposob_vvoda(int *x, double *N, double *U1, double *U2, double *tn, double *t1, double *t2, double *tk) {
    printf("Выберите способ ввода данных:\n 1.С клавиатуры \n 2.Из файла\n");
    scanf("%d", x);
    switch(*x) 
    {
        case 1: 
            klav(&N, &U1, &U2, &tn, &t1, &t2, &tk);
            break;
        case 2: 
            vvod_iz_faila(&N, &U1, &U2, &tn, &t1, &t2, &tk);
            break; 
    }
}
```

Файл `vvod_iz_faila.c`

```
#include "function.h"
void vvod_iz_faila(double *N, double *U1, double *U2, double *tn, double *t1, double *t2, double *tk) {
    FILE *input;
    if( (input=fopen("input.txt","r")) == 0 ) { 
        printf("Ошибка открытия файла");
    }
    fscanf(input, "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", N, U1, U2, tn, t1, t2, tk);
    printf("vy vveli %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", N, U1, U2, tn, t1, t2, tk);
    fclose(input);
}
```

Программа выводит следующее:

```
Выберите способ ввода данных:
 1.С клавиатуры 
 2.Из файла
2
vy vveli 2337384 2337392 2337400 2337408 2337416 2337424 2337432
ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ SUCCESSFUL (общее время: 5s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательно на числа, которые напечатались - они подозрительно отличаются на 8. А все потому, что печатаете Вы адреса.

Поэтому, первое, что нужно исправить, это печатать значения, а не адреса.

```
printf("vy vveli %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", *N, *U1, *U2, *tn, *t1, *t2, *tk);
```

Но есть ещё одна штука.

```
vvod_iz_faila(&N, &U1, &U2, &tn, &t1, &t2, &tk);
```

Здесь N, U1 и подобное - это уже адреса. И вы передаете адрес адреса. Это точно то, что нужно?

Comment: Проблема решилась, путем добавления операторов разыменования * в выводе. Спасибо:) На счет функции vvod_iz_faila, туда действительно поступают адреса, ведь формальные параметры этой функции имеют тип double *

Answer (score 2):

[[@Иван Кущёв](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2), раз решилась, значит Вы еще и `%d` на `%lf` в `fscanf()`  заменили?

**Обновление**

Тогда поменяйте.

Правильно:

```
double d;

scanf("%lf", &d); printf("%f\n", d);
```

или с функцией

```
void f(double *d) {
  scanf("%lf", d);
}
int main () {
  double d;
  f(&d); printf("%f\n", d);
}
```

**Обновление**

Если честно, то я сомневаюсь, что она (как Вы описали изменения, я же не вижу всего действующего сейчас кода) действительно правильно работает. По идее ввод по адресу double в формате `%d` никак не может дать правильного значения.

---

Вкратце, что касается `%f` и `%lf`:

- При передачи в функцию `float` преобразуется в `double`. Поэтому для печати обоих типов используется `%f` (`%lf` тоже подойдет).
- А вот при вводе `scanf` как-то же должен отличать 4-х байтный `float` (формат `%f`) от 8-ми байтного `double` (формат `%lf`).

Подробнее см. `man 3 scanf` и `man 3 printf`.

Comment: @avp, нет, не менял.

Comment: @avp, а поясните, почему именно так, ведь программа работает и без lf? И еще, почему Вы в scanf() пишите %lf, а в printf() пишите просто %f?